# Using JQuery to Hide links based on URL value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(".rfr-col-title").css("display", "none");
```

I would like to hide this class .rfr-col-title if the url contains **abc/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID=**

http://win-e98sopqc735/**abc/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID=**

Comment: The url of the page or the link?

Comment: The fact that he/she wants to hide an entire class if the "url contains.." would lead me to believe that it's the location.href not a.href, otherwise what would be the point of hiding an entire class of links if one contains said string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("abc/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID=") > -1) {
  jQuery(".rfr-col-title").hide();
}
```

Comment: I noticed that as soon as i posted it. check now.

Comment: concept is the same. Sorry, quick answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery way would be to do an attribute selector:

```
$('a[href*="abc/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID="]').hide();
```

The `*=` means "contains".

You could also use `^=` for "begins with" or `$=` for "ends with".

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dQFJe/

Attribute selector docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

**Edit**

I just reread the question.  Are you talking about the url of the page?  If so, you have to do an `if` statement on a window location match:

```
if(window.location.href.match("abc/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID=")) {
    $(".rfr-col-title").hide();
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EyVr4/

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var url = window.location.pathname;


if ("url:contains('abc/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID=')"){
    $(".rfr-col-title").hide();

}
```

Comment: I'm very confused what this is supposed to do. Even with the quotes removed, it's not valid JS.

Comment: what url is returing, when you use "var url = window.location.pathname;
"

Comment: Right, but your `if` condition has some issues. 1) It will _always_ evaluate to true because it is a string literal, and therefore "truthy". 2) JavaScript doesn't have a `contains` method. 3) Even if JavaScript did have a `contains` method, you can't invoke it with a `:`. 4) If you were trying to use jQuery's [contains pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), it would need to be used in a selector context (e.g., `$('.foo:contains(...)')`), not to mention that `:contains` is only used for searching the tag body, not the `href` attribute.

Comment: The above comment feels like it came across snobbish, so sorry about that. I don't mean to be critical - just trying to understand the solution you provided.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery do have a [attribute contain selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). So you can do this:

```
$('a[href*="abc/Lists/abc/DispForm.aspx?ID="]').hide();
```

Instead of `.css('display', 'none')` use `.hide()`